# How to add a var to href 

Tags: javascript, dom, href

I need something like this:

```
var link = " http://www.google.com";

<a href='link' />
```

So I need to use a variable as `href` attribue of a link. Is this possible?

It worked with  `"<a href= '" + link + "' />"`. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the href value on the server, it is bad design to use scripting for this.

However, to answer the question, it can be done by using script to set the href property of the A element once it is in the DOM, e.g.:

```
<a href="<a useful URI if javascript not available>" id="a0">foo</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var a = document.getElementById('a0');
  if (a) {
    a.href = "http://www.google.com";
  }
</script>
```

Of course there are a thousand other ways, all with their pitfalls. So set the value on the server and avoid them all.

```
-- 
Rob
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery this would be

```
var link = "http://www.google.com";
$("a[href='link']").attr("href", link);
```

Though this would not degrade gracefully should javascript be turned off and you'd probably want to use something else rather than selecting by the href anyways.

Comment: Jetpacks _are_ JavaScript. It's not possible to run them with JavaScript turned off.

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually writing both of those lines of code, it would be much easier to use write

`<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>`

Otherwise, you will need to use JavaScript to set the `href` property of your link, which will require getting a reference to it (which means you should set its `id` property).

So you could write something like:

`<a id="myLink">Google</a>`

and in your JavaScript have:

`document.getElementById("myLink").href=link`

but first, please think about whether this is really necessary (or provide some more details in your question).

Answer (score 0):

You're using Jetpack, so you can do `<a href={link}/>.toXMLString()`.

If all you want to do is create an `<a/>` element, use the following.

```
var anchor = document.createElement("a");
anchor.href = link;
```