# Using JavaScript variable inside an anchor tag's href attribute

Tags: javascript, html

Consider I have a JavaScript variable named `link` which contains a URL like this: `www.google.com`. I need to include this variable in `href` attribute in 2 places, like:

```
<a href="link">link</a>
```

This should return something like this: [Google](http://google.com/)

I tried various ways but failed. Is it possible to do like this? The JavaScript variables should be used at both places.

**Note:**
I need to use the variable inside `<a>`  tag also

Comment: `I tried various ways but failed` Could you at least show us 2 of your tries?

Comment: Can you place the sample code what you tried ?

Comment: I tried something like this:

var link = "www.google.com";

document.write("<a href=\"" + link + "\">" + link + "</a>";

I got the above method from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121491/how-to-add-a-var-to-href

Comment: @user3678812 please update your question and add the additional info there, so that any future readers can understand the problem easily..

Comment: @user3678812 do you have the text that should be updated inside the link, or do we have to extract it from the link..?

Comment: we have to extract it from the link. We don't have the text.

Comment: @TJ we have to extract it from the link. We don't have the text. That is where I am having problems. If link = www.google.com, It should print www.google.com and when clicked, it should go to www.google.com..

Comment: What is the context and purpose of doing this? Why are you building links with JavaScript (making them ignored by Google)?

Comment: sorry ppl, where is jQuery's tag ?

Comment: @l2aelba why this question require a query tag..?

Comment: @TJ I meant why ppl answered in jQuery

Comment: @l2aelba haha.. i'm also wondering the same.. 0__0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assume you have the following in your HTML

```
<a href="link" class='dynamicLink'>link</a>
<a href="link" class='dynamicLink'>link</a>
```

You can do the following

```
var href = 'http://www.google.com'; //any other link as wish
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('dynamicLink');

Array.from(links).forEach(link => {
  link.href = href;
  link.innerHTML = href.replace('http://', '');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dBuv6/2/)

Comment: href should be absolute URL with http://. the value you have given will not work.

Comment: @NitishDhar the variable is for demo purpose. it has nothing to do with the solution, it can be anything the OP wants, **IT CAN EVEN BE AN INTERNAL LINK** like `#demo`

Comment: I just specified that this is a very common mistake people make while giving href & wanted to point that out. Please update your answer I will be able to upvote the answer.

Comment: @NitishDhar updated as you mentioned for better understanding.. :)

Comment: @TJ this code almost worked. but when I implemented it, instead of going to www.google.com, it is going to github.io/www.google.com. It is acting as a sub url. I am getting a result like http://currentsite.com/www.google.com. Rest all is good. How can I tackle this ?

Comment: it's not the problem with the script, it's the problem with the website where you're implementing the code, they are restricting it…

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following code.

```
<a id="myLink" href="link">link</a>
```

in your javascript try

```
<script>
    var link = "http://www.google.com/";
    document.getElementById('myLink').setAttribute("href",link);
    document.getElementById('myLink').innerHTML = link;
    // Here the link is your javascript variable that contains the url.
</script>
```

Comment: I think he wants to add the content of the var `link` inside the tag `<a>` too.

Comment: @user3678812 To get rid of the confusion edit your question and paste the entire html or javascript code what you're using. So we'll get what you exactly you want

Comment: @user3678812 I've updated the code little bit. Let me know is this what you're looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for any typo. Writing on my phone. Can't you create the anchor on the fly?

```
anchor =Document.createElement (...)
anchor.href=yourvar-value
anchor.innerText=your-value?
```

If a more complex thing is needed search for javascript databiding on Google

Take care

Answer (score -1):

You can do this easy by jquery.

1st give your  a class/id.

```
<a class="mylink">link</a>
```

Then you can do something like:

```
<script  type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function () {
   $("a.mylink").attr("href", link);
});

</script>
```

If you want the text to change as well you will have to add

```
$("a.mylink").text(link);
```

to `$(document).ready` as well.

See it working:
http://jsfiddle.net/symXp/

Comment: I need to use the variable inside the <a> tag also.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle or something so we can see exactly what sort of thing it is that you need

Comment: If I use your code, it will print "link" which when clicked will take me to the url saved in the variable. Instead of that, I need to print the variable itself like : www.google.com and when clicked, it should go to that destination. 

I can't use any strings. I have to use the variable always.

Comment: then do something like $("a.mylink").text(link); in document.ready

Comment: @Hamster in the working example link, you have initialized the variable inside the function. But in my case it is a global javascript variable which intakes user input. When I used the global variable in your code, it didn't work !

Comment: Well, I can only help you with that if I see your code.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this -

**WORKING DEMO** - http://codepen.io/nitishdhar/pen/rJLEH

**HTML Part**

```
<a href="" class="link">Link will be filled by javascript</a>
```

You need to place a specific class in the a tag. We will need this to get hold of this element from jQuery.

**Javascript Part (Using jQuery)**

```
var link = "http://google.com";
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.link').attr('href', link);
});
```

We need to create a variable, link, which will hold the URL you want to assign to the a tag. Then on document ready, we get hold of the a element & update its href attribute with the link.

Comment: instead of "Link will be filled by javascript", I need to print the value of var link there too. Howcan I modify this code to achieve that ?

Comment: @user3678812 - you can only use javascript variables in javascript code block. So the only way to make a value of a javascript variable reach your html element, you need to do that from javascript i. you will have to modify the html element from javascript only